# Is there any payment gateway in India like payfone.com

Tags: mobile, payment-gateway, payment

Can anyone suggest, is there any payment gateway available in India like payfone.com to deduct the charges directly from the user mobile service provider account and transfer it to the merchant account.

If so is there any api available to integrate it to Magento?

Thanks,
JP

Answer (score 0):

Here's a fairly new service I came across [Tiwala](http://tiwala.co/sms-payments)
They offer multiple payment options including sms payments, Cash on Delivery and [Bank Transfers](http://tiwala.co/bank-transfers) all through an api.
Currently looks like it's invite only.

Comment: Thanks Albert. I don't find any api that are being exposed by them.

Comment: Sounds a little bit spammy to me.